# Querying big data

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with a system that takes in a 50/s 10kb write stream which runs 24 hours a day. The data is ingested via a messaging system in to a sql database, and then used in an overnight aggregation that takes around 15 hours to produce queryable data for an application.

This is currently all in sql, but we are moving to a new architecture.

The plan is to move the ingested writes in to a distributed database like Cassandra or dynamodb, and then perform the aggregation in hadoop. This makes those parts of the system scalable.

My question is, when people have this architecture, where do they put the data after the writes and aggregation have been performed so that it can be queried.

In more detail:

The query model our application uses is quite complicated, to make the data queryable in cassandra, we would have to denormalise it for all queries, this is possible, but would mean a massive growth in data size. Is this normal practice? Or would you prefer to move the data back in to sql?

We could move the data in to redshift, but this seems to be more for ad hoc data analytics, and its purpose is not to be  the backend for a data analytics application. I also think the queries are too complicated in their current form to be written in an orm which is what is required for redshift.

Does this mean that I still need to put the data in to sql server?

I am looking for examples of what people are doing at the moment.

I am sorry this question is a bit abstract, please do not close it, I will add more detail. I have read lots on big data, but most articles are about the ingestion of data using messaging / workers and distributed databases, but I have not found any that show what they do with this ingested data and how it is queried from the application.

***answer to JosefN's comment:** Yes, we are not planning to denormalise in to a sql db. The choice is, denormalise in to cassandra, for all clients and queries, this would probably mean 100x the current data size, as there will be so much duplication in the denormalised model. The other option is to store it as it is now, so that it is queryable, but then, is my only option a sql db?

***after more research I have more information. The best options at the moment seems to be:**

- store back in sql
- denormalise in cassandra
- use one of the real time sql engines on top of hadoop / hdfs like impala
- drpc with storm

I do not have any experience with Impala or DRPC with storm, so if anyone has any info on latency and the type of queries that can be performed with these that would be great.

Please do not refer to documentation or blog posts, I know how these technologies work, I only want to know if someone has used them in production and has their own information on this subject. thanks

Comment: Definitely it is not good idea to store big denormalized  data in SQL db. It is possible to prepare several query models optimized for different queries. I would not worry so much about data size. Cassandara or HBase scale well. Looking forward for more specification

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the aggregated data into HDFS. Using Hive, which provides a relational view over data stored inside HDFS, you can very well use adhoc sql like queries. At the same time you will be benefitted from parallelism of MapReduce jobs that gets invoked when you use Hive. This would help you to decrease query latencies that you would be having while using a RDBMS. Also think about doing the aggregation jobs in Hadoop itself.

Comment: Thanks Hussain. We will be doing the aggregation in Hadoop. I am asking, in the architecture that I have mentioned above (message / worker / distributed database / hadoop), similar to other big data solutions, once the aggregation has been performed, what are the options, or what are people using for instant querying (response time under 1 second) to support an application. Either denormalising in cassandra, or putting the data back in sql db? Or are there other options that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

Since the data after aggregation is small and you are looking for good latency keeping it in hdfs and query it using hive is not preferable. 
I have seen people using hbase to store aggregated data and query it but as you mentioned earlier you will have to denormalize the data. For this case I will recommend writing aggregated data back to mysql and query it there if aggregated data is not big.

Comment: thanks, the data after aggregation is not small, apologies if i gave that impression. It is still around 3-5TB of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think one traditional approach is to run your Hadoop/Hive jobs to aggregate across all possible dimensions, and then store in a key/value store like HBase, and look up at runtime with a key based on the aggregation done ( ie. /state=NJ/dt=20131225/ )  This can cause an explosion in size, especially if there are many dimensions to roll up

If you want/need a more realtime solution as well, take a look at Twitter's summingbird.

Comment: thanks, yes, I am considering denormalisation in to cassandra, and am aware of the explosion of data size as mentioned in the question. Thanks for the summingbird tip, I was not aware of it, although what I am looking for is information on using it for real time querying.